# Django + rest-framework: serialize arbitrary query

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have three classes representing different sections in my models: `SectionA`, `SectionB`, `SectionC`. 
Each of these sections have associated a set of items (class `Item` in my model).

I would like to get a json similar to this:

```
{
"sectionA": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "picture": "car_pic1", 
            "category": "cat1"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "picture": "car_pic1", 
            "category": "cat2"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 5, 
            "picture": "car_pic1", 
            "category": "cat3"
        }
],
"sectionB": [
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "picture": "car_pic1", 
            "category": "cat8"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 4, 
            "picture": "car_pic1", 
            "category": "cat9"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 7, 
            "picture": "car_pic1", 
            "category": "cat10"
        }, 
],
 "sectionC": [
            {
                "id": 9, 
                "picture": "car_pic1", 
                "category": "cat9"
            }, 
            {
                "id": 10, 
                "picture": "car_pic1", 
                "category": "cat9"
            }, 
            {
                "id": 11, 
                "picture": "car_pic1", 
                "category": "cat10"
            }, 
]
}
```

This json displays any three items associated to each section.

I would like to know how can I implement this using rest-framework. Basically I need to perform a query retrieving the three items for each section (since this json is not associated to a model object) and serialize all this into the json. I'm not sure where or how to perform these queries and I didn't have any success so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I did it slightly different. My view just creates a dictionary with each section and its associated items:

```
class SectionList(APIView):
    """
    List three objects for each section.
    """
    def generate_data(self):
        #query to get the items of each section

        list_items = []
        list_items.append({"section" : "sectionA", "items" : secA_items})
        list_items.append({"section" : "sectionB", "items" : secB_items})
        list_items.append({"section" : "sectionC", "items" : secC_items})

        return list_items;

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        section_list = self.generate_data()
        serializer = SectionSerializer(section_list)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this is the serializer I used:

```
class SectionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    section = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True)
```